# ecryptfs-recover-private doesn't accept my login passphrase

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

Ubuntu Live DVD (14.04 or 14.10)

```
$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private

INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
INFO: Found [/media/ubuntu/4aaa62c3-5a78-4054-b804-2476d6c4ec42/.ecryptfs/pacmo/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: Y 
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] Y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase:
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
```

Why ? I insert my login password exactly

Comment: Wrong password, apparently. And, `Check the system log for more information`, i.e. with `dmesg` or see `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: /var/log/syslog
Apr 30 14:42:59 ubuntu ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Incorrect wrapping key for file [/media/ubuntu/4aaa62c3-5a78-4054-b804-2476d6c4ec42/.ecryptfs/pacmo/.Private/../.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]
Apr 30 14:42:59 ubuntu ecryptfs-insert-wrapped-passphrase-into-keyring: Error attempting to unwrap passphrase from file [/media/ubuntu/4aaa62c3-5a78-4054-b804-2476d6c4ec42/.ecryptfs/pacmo/.Private/../.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]; rc = [-5]

Comment: Password is ok, because if I boot ubuntu, it's ok and I known my password. I don't have lost my data, I can access to my data, I haven't problems. But I want to try the recover for the future.  If in the future  I have problems to access my data, I would recover and I would be ready.

Comment: I'm not sure about it then... double-check the actual folder locations? Try `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase` on the wrapped-passphrase file? **BUT** it's always easier to make a backup NOW, when you can still read the data, than it is to try recovery after you're having problems. *PS. The "answer" on the marked duplicate Q is basically "I had the wrong password" I think, not very helpful...*